# Faster MySQL Queries?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

At my work I have several tables with over 200,000 rows of data. I have to set-up some queries that look over 15,000+ at a time so sometimes I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution
>   time of 180 seconds exceeded

So, how do I speed up faster queries?

The query is like this:

```
SELECT  toemail, toname
FROM    email_sent
WHERE   companyid = '$member[companyid]'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without any example data, queries, or table structure.

Comment: This is a pretty general and unspecified question. General answers: try to reduce the number of rows you need to look at, read up on database optimization, consider adding indexes if appropriate, throw bigger faster better hardware at it, etc etc.

Comment: Let's have a look at the structure of the queries.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning RDBMS you are using, this would help to answer your question. Could you please post some of your queries? This would help even more.

Comment: SELECT toemail,toname FROM `email_sent` WHERE `companyid` = '$member[companyid]' 

something like that

Comment: @Dan - Do you have an index on the companyid column?

Comment: No, I heard it's faster to search through but slower to insert...

Comment: @Dan: indices *can* slow down inserts and updates. It's usually not too bad but sometimes you may have to decide if you want faster queries and slower updates/inserts, or faster updates/inserts and slower queries. Usually depends on if your application is read-heavy or write-heavy.

Comment: The slowness of the reads with no index will far outshadow changes to writes with an index. With an index, the new ID must be added to the index - but with no index, it probably has to do a full table scan for every single select. That's very inefficient, as you experienced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an index on `email_sent (company_id)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_emailsent_companyid ON email_sent (company_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimization might be the answer. If it's not enough, you can always just increase PHP's time limit.

This will set it for just that script:

[set_time_limit docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> Set the number of seconds a script is
>   allowed to run. If this is reached,
>   the script returns a fatal error. The
>   default limit is 30 seconds or, if it
>   exists, the max_execution_time value
>   defined in the php.ini.

Or, edit php.ini and change the [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) setting. This will change it globally, of course. It sounds like it has already been adjusted (by your sysadmin?) as the default is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index if you haven't already.
Another way is to switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: You forgot to mention another option: switching from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM`.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you might want to look into is indexing any columns which participate in the query. For example, if you your query is always testing the value of a column `FirstName`, you might want to index that.

If you provide a DDL (Data Definition Lanaguage) script or a description of the tables, as well as the queries that are taking so long, we might be able to provide better tips for indexing.

If you've already tuned as much as you can and you still get timeouts, you might want to see if you can increase the transaction timeout limit. I don't know enough about your server setup to give details, but that sort of thing is *usually* possible.

**UPDATE**

If your query is:

```
SELECT toemail,toname FROM email_sent WHERE companyid  = '$member[companyid]'
```

My first question is: do you have an index on `companyid` and if not, does creating one improve performance?